# Objective-C NSData initWithContentsOfFile, check if file exists?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

Should I check if a file exists at a given path when trying to read the data into an `NSData` object? Right now I'm not doing at the moment but my code works since my array that is supposed to get populated with data from the file will be set to nil and I can later in my application check if that array is nil. But I'm thinking that the code is perhaps "ugly" and would work better if i did a check (like the one in the commented code).

```
NSData *codedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[CareersParser dataFilePath]];

    /*
    if (codedData != nil) {
        //do the below (not commented out code)
    } else {

        //file doesn't exist at the given path
        [codedData release];
        return nil;
    }
    */

    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:codedData];
    NSArray *careers = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kDataKey];    
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    NSMutableArray *ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Career *career in careers) {
        [ids addObject:[career id]];
    }

    // Sort the array in an orderly fashion
    NSArray *sortedIds = [ids sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    // Release allocated memory
    [ids release];
    [unarchiver release];
    [codedData release];

    return sortedIds;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems sensible to me I would reverse the if statement to do away with the else clause.

```
if (nil == codedDate) {
  [codedData release];
  return nil;
}

... Do the rest of your code
```

Apple suggests [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that you should attempt to perform an operation such as loading data like you have suggested. As long as you don't try to do `[[NSManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]` you won't be introducing race conditions.

Comment: How would a race situation occur when using `fileExistsAtPath` method?

Comment: First example I can think of is if you are using `fileExistsAtPath` to verify that your required directory structure is set up e.g. `Documents/myAppFiles/test.txt` upon receiving `YES` you might be happy and go ahead and save the file. It is possible that between your check and the save operation that a background thread could come and remove the directory structure you are reliant on which would cause your file to not save. There is more info in the apple docs http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't, and this could introduce a race, so it will be more "ugly". Just check if *codedData* if nil in case of reading failure.